# Redmine email notification error " An error occurred while sending mail (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) "

Tags: redmine

I am using redmine 2.5 version, last one week email notification are not working. It's worked before. Now getting error " An error occurred while sending mail (getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution) ".

This is my email configuration

```
email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: smtp.rediffmail.com
      port: 25
     # ssl: true
     # enable_starttls_auto: true
      domain: rediffmail.com
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "XXXXXX@rediffmail.com"
      password: "XXXX"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Redime problem, but a DNS problem. Check if you can send the mail to the problematic address from your standard email client.